# How do I perform a while left mouse is down?

Tags: python, input, mouse, pynput

I'm trying to run a while loop until the mouse button is released.

I have tried doing something like this using pynput

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

mouse = False

# This function will be called when any key of mouse is pressed
def on_click(*args):
    # see what argument is passed.
    print(args)
    if args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        print('The "{}" mouse key has held down'.format(args[-2].name))
        mouse = True
        while mouse:
            # Do stuff

    elif not args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        print('The "{}" mouse key is released'.format(args[-2].name))
        mouse = False

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

but it never stops.
Is there a way i can just await the mouse up event?
Some kind of condition to put in the while loop like

```
while mouse_down:
    # Do stuff until the mouse is released
```

I've also tried the python mouse libary but it was just acting unexpectedially.
Basically i want a while loop to run everytime i press the left mouse *until* i release it.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that continually loops, monitoring the `mouse` variable.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

mouse = False

def on_click(*args):
    global mouse
    if args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        mouse = True
    elif not args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        mouse = False

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    while True:
        if mouse:
            print("Doing stuff while the mouse is down...")
```

And here's a version that uses an `threading.Event` instead of polling.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
from threading import Event

event = Event()

def on_click(*args):
    if args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        event.set()
    elif not args[-1] and args[-2].name == 'left':
        event.clear()

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    while event.wait():
        print("Doing stuff while the mouse is down....")
```

Neither of these versions exits gracefully, but I am not familiar enough with `pynput.mouse` to fix that.